# Calculating propellant mass from total impulse

Tags: rockets, fuel, specific-impulse

I have a simple question about how to calculate the total propellant mass used by a satellite in space.
From Simulink, I have a graph of thrust VS time, so I could integrate this to calculate the total impulse.
How can I compute the total propellant mass used by the satellite from this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'd ignore the total impulse and start with the thrust instead.  Take the [rocket thrust equation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rockth.html)

Thrust$=\dot{m}V_e + (p_e-p_0)A_e$

Solve for $\dot{m}$, the mass flow rate through the nozzle, then integrate THAT in time for your total mass used in the burn.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simplest case: constant thrust for a given time. Thrust is $\dot{m}c$ where the first is flow rate and $c$ is effective exhaust velocity. So,
$total impulse=  Ft=\dot{m}ct=M_pc$

where $M_p$ is the total propellant used. In SI units, $F$ in newtons, c in m/s, $M_p$ in kg and $\dot{m}$ in kg/s. If you use F in pounds-force and $M_p$ in pounds-mass, then use specific impulse for $c$.

Integration of F with time should give the same equation.

Comment: Thank you very much!